# How can I export a c++ function, declared in .h file to R package without loosing default arguments?

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package

I'm trying to create an R package with c++ code. I have a header inst/include/mypack.h, which contains a declaration of my function:

```
int func(int x, int y=1);
```

This function is defined in one of the .cpp files:

```
int foo(int x, int y=1) {
  return x + y;
}
```

And I also use it in the other .cpp files (so I have to declare it in a separate .h file).

How can I export this function in R without loosing the default value for y? If I add *// [[Rcpp::export]]* to the .h file, Rcpp just doesn't export it (RcppExports.R doesn't contain this function), and if I add the export to the .cpp file, Rcpp doesn't parse the default argument.

Comment: Simply put: You cannot. One of the other...

Comment: Can you wrap create a wrapper function for the one called from R?

Comment: @rsmith54, actually I can, but if I create two sets of default parameters I should pay additional attention to keep them consistent.

Comment: @coatless, thanks for the answer, but I hope someone can know a dirty trick for doing such things :)